# Silverlight app freezes on Mac when file saved

Tags: macos, silverlight, freeze

Pretty simple code to launch `SaveFileDialog` and then save data.
Opens prompt, I can select where I save, it saves file and then whole tab/app freezes. Obviously works fine on Windows/IE. Any suggestions?

```
private void SavePDFFile()
        {
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
                                     {
                                         DefaultExt = "pdf",
                                         Filter = string.Format("Document(.{0})|*.{0}", "pdf"),
                                         FilterIndex = 1,
                                         DefaultFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmMMddyyyy")
                                     };

            var saveClicked = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (!saveClicked.HasValue || !saveClicked.Value) return;
            var fileStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();

            try
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;
                fileStream.Write(this.PDFData, 0, this.PDFData.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.DisplayErrorMessage("Error saving PDF file", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you please review my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. This is nothing to do with code itself. It is security issue. In order to allow this code to execute on Mac (and it seems new versions of IE as well) you need to give it more permissions.

On IE you need to add website to list of Trusted sites.

On Mac - you need to set Silverlight to run in "Unsafe" mode. This is in Preferences/Security/Silverlight and need to select website, hold "Option" key and then open dropdown to see that option. Took a while to find it..

Answer (score 0):

@katit I also faced this issue while working on a Silverlight OOB application.. my app was working fine in Windows but in Mac it got freezed and I have to force quit to use it again.

I was actually reading a PDF (stored in field type - 'varbinary') from server and storing it to user's local machine.

The solution worked for me is to download file chunks in parts (I used buffer size - 1 MB).

Not sure what file size you are using when your application gets freeze.. but I think, writing 'PDFData' to filestream in small parts may help you.

Also, add filestream.Flush(); (see highlighted in below code) in your code and see if this helps:

```
private void SavePDFFile()
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
                                 {
                                     DefaultExt = "pdf",
                                     Filter = string.Format("Document(.{0})|*.{0}", "pdf"),
                                     FilterIndex = 1,
                                     DefaultFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmMMddyyyy")
                                 };

        var saveClicked = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (!saveClicked.HasValue || !saveClicked.Value) return;
        var fileStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();

        try
        {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            fileStream.Write(this.PDFData, 0, this.PDFData.Length);
            **filestream.Flush();**
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.DisplayErrorMessage("Error saving PDF file", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, this is not what my problem was.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for answering. I thought if it was due to large size of file.